# String formatting of List element without bracket

Tags: java, string

Consider

```
    List<String> explanationsteps = new ArrayList<String>();
    explanationsteps.add("The prime factorization for each number is ");
```

When I sysout the String appears to be like this:

```
[The prime factorization for each number is]
```

Because of Array type, i want to Store in a local String variable where i can get simple output like:

```
The prime factorization for each number is
```

without square bracket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way

```
explanationsteps.get(0).toString();
```

It is because you are using the collection in which the `toString` method is overloaded to display the contents of the list. If you would have more than one string in it then it would have been
`[sentence 1, sentence 2, sentence 3]`

If you wish you may use Array of strings

```
String[] explanationsteps = new String[100];  //size say 100 (as per your requirement)  
explanationsteps[0] = "your sentence";
```

Comment: its works. but what will happen when keep on adding the contain such as explanationsteps.add("a");  explanationsteps.add("b"); though adding may depend upon the condition. i mean its dynamically adding and using only get(0) will return me only the 0 index..?

Comment: Yes. You're correct. You'll get first element only. That's how you described what you want your code to do. If you want something else please describe.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing toString() on the ArrayList.
As a result you get toString() of the entire list instead of 1 element. Also if there's more than one element in the list, they will all get listed within those square brackets. Not sure if that what you ultimately wanted.

In order to print string as it is just do this:

```
explanationsteps.get(0).toString();
```

Comment: You have to do it on the element, not on the list.

Comment: You're probably doing explanationsteps.toString(), instead you have to do explanationsteps.get(0).toString().

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using this;

```
System.out.println(explanationsteps);
```

But, you must try this for getting output that what you want;

```
System.out.println(explanationsteps.get(0));
```